# Confidence interval on R-squared

Tags: r, confidence-interval, r-squared

I know that it is possible when you realize a multiple linear regression to calculate the confidence interval on the R-squared and on the adjusted R-squared. Does somebody know how to do it with R?

Answer (score 6):

You probably can be served by the `CI.Rsq` function in the psychometric package. The equation is provided in the help. An alternative would be bootstrapping the CI.

Comment: I believe this requires n>60 or so - wonder if there is a more general or exact solution?
Troels

Comment: I'm not sure recommendations for n > 60 for the CI are really any different from recommendations of n for the regression in the first place. Poor parameter estimates lead to poor CI estimates. That will be true regardless of how they are calculated. A more complex approach would be to bootstrap the model directly but there's not enough information in the question to help with that.